# hide and show div when page loads based on result generated from php

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am doing API call to box.net.
I wanted to show data from the response into a table.
But sometimes response is empty.
that time i want to show user some message.

So my idea is to show `div` containing table when i get some response and disable `div` containing  message. and vice versa.

I an new to jquery. Didn't find suitable examples.
I tried something from those examples,but it was not successful.
here is

```
if (sizeof($folder_entries) == 0) 
    {
        echo '<script>';
        echo '$("#message").show()';
        echo '$("#content").hide()';
        echo '</script>';
    }
    else 
    {
        echo '<script>';
        echo '$("#message").hide()';
        echo '$("#content").show()';
        echo '</script>'; 
}
```

How can i get that?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What do you have so far? What did you try, and what kind of response do you get, in what format?

Comment: Is the API call to box.net AJAX or is it in PHP?

If it's in PHP, all you have to use is an if statement surely..

Answer (score 0):

seems like you need straightforward javascript or jquery to show and hide the div

```
<script>
if (some condition..... )
      {
            document.getElementById("test").style.display  = '';       
      }
      else
      {
            document.getElementById("test").style.display  = 'none';
      }
 </script>

<div name="test" id="test">
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#hideh1').click(function(){
   $('div.showhide,h1').hide();
 });
 $('#showh1').click(function(){
   $('div.showhide,h1').show();
 });
 $('#toggleh1').click(function(){
   $('div.showhide,h1').toggle();
 });
```

});